# Text editors which treat emulated tabs exactly the same as true tabs?

Tags: text-editor

Do you know of any text editor that, when configured to use emulated tabs (issuing spaces when you hit the tab key) will change the cursor key behaviour so that it behaves the same as with true tabs, jumping by multiples of the number of spaces in an emulated tab instead of moving space by space?

I mean, if you configure emulated tabs to 4 spaces, then if you hit the tab key you get 4 spaces, so if you need later to navigate through that tab, you would need to press the cursor key 4 times.

There's of course the alternative of pressing Alt+Cursor key, which moves to the next non-blank character in the line, but I'd like to know if there's any editor that actually emulates tabs so radically than even the cursor keys behave as if they weren't spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) (free) and Sublime Text both can be used so, but with plugin. Plugin is not existing yet.

The tip how to write this plugin for CudaText: plugin must handle on_key event (better for only keycodes of LEFT/RIGHT, it's option in install.inf). In this event, plugin must disable default action by returning False, and run its own action by using `ed.cmd()`.